# Unmarshalling a nested Set using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb

Sorry for the long post, thank you in advance!

---

I need to unmarshall this XML:

```xml
<RootTag>

  <Container type="type1">
    <value name="name1"/>
    <value name="name2"/>
  </Container>

  <Container type="type2">
    <value name="name3"/>
    <value name="name4"/>
  </Container>

</RootTag>
```

---

**Summary**

Inside my JAXB (the code is below) I have a Set of Sets of values, where the inner set is wrapped into a *Container* class. So, I have a Set of containers of values, where a value is a generic class. Problem: values do not get resolved unless the chosen generic class is hardcoded.

---

**Detailed**

Notes on the XML:

- `<Container>` tag contains a *Set* of `<value>` tags. The `<value>` tag may contain anything. In the JAXB, the *Container* class uses *Set<T>* (in the example above we have an *ElementName* class, that has only one "name" attribute).
- There are only supposed to be exactly two `<Container>` tags (its attribute is an *enum* of two items, but in this example it is just a *String* to make it simpler). **Additional question** (optional): is there any way to limit the quantity of the tag to exactly two (no more, no less)?

Wrapping all of that, we have a *Root* class that has `Set<Container<ElementName>>`. The problem is that the deepest `ElementName` (that is supposed to represent the `<value>` tag) class does not get resolved by JAXB (too many levels of indirection?). However, JAXB reads all the information into its internal type `ElementNSImpl` (I figured it out by placing a breakpoint inside the `afterUnmarshall` method) where it has the attributes' values of the tags (that is, `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, and `name4`). Unmarshalling completes without errors, but when I try to access any `<value>` tag I get this:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to ElementName
```

Inside the *Container* class, I specify the tag name of the `<value>` using

```java
@XmlElement(name = "value")
```

If I just hardcode the type here like so:

```java
@XmlElement(name = "value", type = ElementName.class)
```

Then JAXB resolves the tag properly. But, as I said, the class is supposed to be generic, so that is not really a solution for me.

---

**JAXB classes**

*Root*

```java
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/*
 * <RootTag>
 *     *
 * </RootTag>
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "RootTag")
public class Root {

    /* <Container type = "type1">
     *   <value name = "name1"/>
     *   <value name = "name2"/>
     * </Container>
     * <Container type = "type2">
     *   <value name = "name3"/>
     *   <value name = "name4"/>
     * </Container>
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "Container")
    private Set<Container<ElementName>> containers;

    // for each of the two Container types 
    // we create a set of its corresponding values' names
    // and then we null the containers field
    @XmlTransient
    private Map<String, Set<String>> valuesNames = new HashMap<>(2);

    //Basically that is @PostConstruct, but works with JAXB
    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {

        containers.forEach(container -> valuesNames.put(container.getType(),
                                                        container.getValues().stream()
                                                                 .map(ElementName::getName)
                                                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet())));
        containers = null;
    }

    /** return unique value names from both container types */
    public Set<String> getAllValuesNames() {

        return valuesNames.values().stream()
                          .flatMap(Set::stream)
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

*Container*

```java
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Set;

/*
 * <* type = "type1">
 *   <value *>*
 *   <value *>*
 * </*>
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public  class Container<T> {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private Set<T> values;

    public String getType() {

        return type;
    }

    public Set<T> getValues() {

        return values;
    }
}
```

*ElementName*

```java
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

/*
 *  <* name = "name2"/>
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ElementName {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }
}
```

---

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    final String xmlSerialized = "<RootTag>\n" +
                                 "  \n" +
                                 "  <Container type=\"type1\">\n" +
                                 "    <value name=\"name1\"/>\n" +
                                 "    <value name=\"name2\"/>\n" +
                                 "  </Container>\n" +
                                 "  \n" +
                                 "  <Container type=\"type2\">\n" +
                                 "    <value name=\"name3\"/>\n" +
                                 "    <value name=\"name4\"/>\n" +
                                 "  </Container>\n" +
                                 "  \n" +
                                 "</RootTag>";

    System.out.println("XML:\n" +
                       "=======================================\n" +
                       xmlSerialized +
                       "\n=======================================");

    //works just the same with only Root.class
    JAXBContext  context      = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, Container.class, ElementName.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    Root xmlDeserialized = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlSerialized));
    System.out.println("Values' names: " + xmlDeserialized.getAllMetricNames());
}
```

In case everything works (if I hardcode the *ElementName.class* in the annotation inside the *Container* class) it gives the following output:

```
XML:
=======================================
<RootTag>
  <Body>
    <Container type="type1">
      <value name="name1"/>
      <value name="name2"/>
    </Container>
    <Container type="type2">
      <value name="name3"/>
      <value name="name4"/>
    </Container>
  </Body>
</RootTag>
=======================================
Values' names: [name4, name3, name2, name1]
```

---

**Things I have tried to far**

[Unmarshalling generic list with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19878229).

1. Main idea is to instead of using `List<T>` use a `Wrapper<T>`, that will use that list internally and give it via getter. My *Container* is kind of already a wrapper except it also has an attribute. But there is the difference in the annotation of the *Set*:

   Before:

   ```
   @XmlElement(name = "value")
   private Set<T> values;
   ```

   After:

   ```
   @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
   private Set<T> values;
   ```
2. Run again (`JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, Container.class, ElementName.class)`): nothing changed, values are still of type `ElementNSImpl`. Also, I don't like that I allow any name for the tag, it must be "value".

[Intermittent ClassCastException from ElementNSImpl to own type during unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377865)

In their case, the problem was that they created `JAXBContext` without providing some of the needed classes. Does not apply to me.

[JAXB Unmarshalling XML Class Cast Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324218)

In their case the problem was Java Type Erasure, that means Java determines generic types at compile-time, then compiles the code and then *erases the types* from the generics, so JVM does not know what are those generic types. I bet that is my case, but I have no idea on how to check or fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I used the approach described [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) by Blaise Doughan, which is the usage of `XmlAdapter` class. I turned set of values into set of Strings adapting `ElementName` to `String`. And then the container to map.

p.s. I kept the `ContainerOfElementName` like in my other answer. That is duplicate code, but it seems there is no better way of creating the JAXB hierarchy.

p.p.s. The problem was (IMHO) with the Java Type Erasure. `Set<Container<ElementName>>` after compilation is just `Set`. I noticed, that JAXB stops resolving generics when you hit the second level of indirection, like `T1<T2>` is fine, but `T1<T2<T3>>` is not.

Answer (score 0):

**Current workaround -- other answers are very welcome**

I leveraged a bit the idea with hardcoding the generic type - I split the *Container* class into two classes and the `<value>` classes are now inner (but I left them public so they can inherit each other):

**Container**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.Set;

/*
 * <Container type = "type1">
 *   *
 * </Container>
 */
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract  class Container {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    public String getType() {

        return type;
    }

    /** Derived classes will declare the generic type for us. */
    public abstract Set<?> getValues();
}
```

**ContainerOfElementName**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/*
 * <Container type = "type1">
 *   <value name="name1"/>
 *   <value name="name2"/>
 * </Container>
 */
public class ContainerOfElementName extends Container {

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private Set<ElementName> values;

    @Override
    public Set<ElementName> getValues() {

        return values;
    }

    public Set<String> getNames() {
        return values.stream().map(v -> v.name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    /*
     *  <* name = "name2"/>
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class ElementName {

        @XmlAttribute
        private String name;
    }
}
```

And now in the *Root* class:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Container")
private Set<ContainerOfElementName> containers;

void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {

    containers.forEach(container -> valuesNames.put(container.getType(),
                                                    container.getNames()));
    containers = null;
}
```

That works, but it forces me to create a child class of the *Container* for each possible class that represents `<value>` which is a lot of boilerplate code.